# Scapy: Processing partial TLS segments

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, tls1.2, scapy

I am trying to extract TLS meta-data from a pcap using Scapy. I am able to successfully parse the packets and individual messages such as the client-hello, server-hello etc and their fields. What I am having trouble with is when the TLS record is spread across multiple TCP packets/segments. This happens mostly for large TLS messages, such as application data or when server sends multiple TLS messages (server hello, certificate, etc) in one TLS frame. In such cases, scapy says it has the TLS/SSLv2 layer, but I am unable to extract any meaningful information from such frames. When I look at the same pcap in wireshark, wireshark displays

```
Reassembled TCP segments (T bytes): #X (x), #Y(y), #Z(z)
```

Where T is the combined total; X, Y, Z are frame-ids and x,y,z are number of bytes in each frame that contributed to the total T. Wireshark is reassembly the entire TLS payload before it parses the TLS frame.

I have something like this in my code:

```
if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.haslayer(TLS):
  parseTLS(pkt)
elif pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.haslayer(SSLv2):
  parseSSLv2(pkt)
```

When it encounters a partial TLS packet, the code always falls through to the SSLv2. Is there a way for me to accurately identify a packet as a partial tls-segment and accumulate and then process the complete TLS frame similar to wireshark? If so, how do I go about it. Any pointers or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A TCP record can spread over multiple actual packets. Any TLS layer information are only contained in the first one - and there can be even data in this from the previous record. The length of this record is contained in the record itself - see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-6.2. Therefore you cannot just treat each packet separately but you have to look at the whole reassembled data stream. You have to treat it only as data stream, i.e. have to ignore packet boundaries because they might not be the TLS record boundaries.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps I wasn't clear, I wanted to know if there were any primitives available in scapy that could tell me if the segment was partial. Similar to haslayer(TLS), I was was wondering if there were any primitives to say ispartial(TLS), accumulate(tls) in case of partial segments. Otherwise, as a user, I have to figure out the tls record length, accumulate the tcppayloads from sevearal individual pkts and then do the necessary processing. Would be best if it was part of the module.

Comment: There is no "partial" segment in TCP. TCP is only a byte stream which can be split in arbitrary ways for transport. You cannot see from a single packet alone how it has to be interpreted at the application level but you always have to look at the context of the previous data for this.

Comment: When I mentioned 'partial' segment, I was asking from an API perspective and not from TCP perspective. I understand TCP is a stream. After spending an hour, I built a simple one that works for my use case. Extract tcp.payload and get tls-record length from the 1st TLS frame. If `record-len > tcp-payload-len`, we can conclude TLS frame is partial. Since I was familiar with TLS protocol, I wrote a TLS frame accumulator and got it working. Scapy, being a library, could do this and provide an API. Since its my first attempt at using scapy, I was hoping it had an such API.

Comment: @DnjAbc I'm working on the same problem that you have mentioned which is extracting TLS meta-data using scapy but I was unable to extract TLS meta-data when I have a packet that contains multiple TLS records. Could you please clarify to me how did you proceed

Comment: I look into the record header in the TLS packet. The first record header len include the size of all handshake messages (one or more). I used this length to figure if I had a partial tls frame or full frame. Then I accumulate bytes from the rest of the frames till I reach record lenght in the first packet. Assumes there are no dropped packets. See the reference implementation in answer. I answered my own question.

Comment: I really didn't understand what you mean by "The first record header len include the size of all handshake messages (one or more)". I can't see this when I look to the paquet that include server Hello, changeCipherSpec and application data messages in TLS 1.3. Could you please explain to me what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better solution, but here's what I did to get around my problem. The accumulated frame-sizes seem to agree with what Wireshark does when it reassembles TLS frame from multiple packets.

**Note**: This solution assumes there are no misordered packets or duplicates. Also, the solution shown here is not complete. The code below only shows how to accumulate TLS frames when they span multiple IP packets for a single TCP stream. Please follow [Janus's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214974/janus-varmarken) suggestion (mentioned in the comments below) or come up with your own solution to accumulate different the streams.

```
def extractDataFromPcap(pcapfile):
  load_layer("tls")

  try:
    reader = PcapReader(pcapfile)

    # tls frame accumulation related variables.
    tls_accumulate = False
    tls_leftover_len = 0
    tls_blist = list()

    for pkt in reader:
      try:
        if tls_accumulate and pkt.haslayer(TCP):
          ip_tcp_hdr_overhead = ((pkt[IP].ihl*4) + (pkt[TCP].dataofs*4))
          pkt_payload_len = (pkt[IP].len - ip_tcp_hdr_overhead)
          tls_leftover_len = (tls_leftover_len - pkt_payload_len)
          tls_blist.append(raw(pkt[TCP].payload))

          if tls_leftover_len <= 0:
            # got complete TLS frame
            tls_raw_bytes = b''.join(tls_blist)

            # parse accumulated frame.
            tls = TLS(tls_raw_bytes)
            #... process tls object

            # reset accumlation variables.
            tls_accumulate = False
            tls_leftover_len = 0
            tls_blist = list()
          else:
            continue

        if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.haslayer(TLS):
          if not tls_accumulate:
            # Process new TLS frame.
            # Pkt over head: ip-hdr-len + tcp-hdr-len
            ip_tcp_hdr_overhead = ((pkt[IP].ihl*4) + (pkt[TCP].dataofs*4))
            pkt_payload_len = (pkt[IP].len - ip_tcp_hdr_overhead)
            if pkt[TLS].len > pkt_payload_len:
              # partial TLS frame. Start accumulating.
              tls_accumulate = True
              tls_leftover_len = (pkt[TLS].len - pkt_payload_len)
              tls_blist.append(raw(pkt[TCP].payload))
            else:
              # complete TLS frame
              # ... process complete TLS Frame 
      except Exception as error:
        pkt.show()
        print("tcp-processing error: %s", error)
        sys.exit(-1)

  except Exception as error:
    print("packet processing error: %s", error)
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: This code only works when we have one TLS record per packet, it's inefficient when we face some packets that have multiple TLS records

Comment: Try to understand before saying things like doesn't work or inefficient. Do you understand the TLS frame format? The 1st pkt contains record hdr which contains the len TLS frame. TLS frame can span multple pkts. Code tries to accum. all bytes from multiple pkts into a big TLS frame (TLS frame can have multi. HS msgs), equal to len in 1st-pkt. Once accumulated, process TLS frame with multiple HS msgs. Above code does not include code to parse multiple HS msgs in a frame, 'cause thats straight forward. Only shows accum. logic (see comment 'complete TLS frame, ... complete TLS frame')

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Should be a good starting point. BTW, I think it would be good to include a subsection in the answer on assumptions (no reordering of packets, no duplicate packets). Also, as far as I can tell, this considers all TCP streams as one. I believe this part could be solved by first calling Scapy's `.sessions()` and then calling your code for each reassembled TCP stream.

Comment: Good suggestion. Will add that.

Comment: I am trying to decode TLS application data for my domain with the legal certificate files and I write some code but It was in error and I am very confused, Please check this out: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790912/decrypt-ssl-tls-with-specific-private-key-via-scapy