# Decrypt SSL/TLS with specific Private Key via SCAPY

Tags: python, ssl, https, utf-8, scapy

I want to decrypt HTTPS traffic for **my domain** on **my server** with scapy.

Then I have the original international registered certificate (**TLS1.3**) files for my domain...

And it **must** be *so much easy* to do this with scapy BUT I can not find any solution anywhere and this is **so crazy**.

For example I was try these solutions, but they **not working** with no **bug** and **crash** :

- [scapy-ssl_tls](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls)
- [scapy-notebook2_tls](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/tls/notebook2_tls_protected.ipynb)
- TSHARK
- ***MITM Solutions***
- SSLDUMP

Finaly I was **writting** a sample **code** BUT it raising below **error** and I try *too much* to fix it but cant understand the problem and clear solution:

***value Error: ciphertext length must be equal to key size***

```
import os, sys
import ssl
from scapy import *
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import *
from scapy.layers.tls import *
from scapy.layers import inet
from scapy.layers.inet import *
import socket, select
import binascii
import io
from io import StringIO

load_layer("tls")
c = Cert("SSL/STAR_mydomain_com.crt")
k=PrivKey("SSL/private.key")

########### Unit-Test Encrypt/Decrypt Run OK ########### 
#M = bytes("message to be encrypted".encode())
#enc = c.encrypt(M, t='oaep')
#print(enc)
#dec = k.decrypt(enc, t='oaep')
#print(dec)

while True:
    s = sniff(filter="port 443", count=10)
    ch_list = [p for p in s]
    if len(ch_list)>0:
        for pkt in ch_list:
            p_layer = pkt.getlayer('IP')
            src = p_layer.src
            dst = p_layer.dst
            if (src=='my-server-ip') or (dst=='my-server-ip'):
                if ('TLSEncryptedContent' in str(type(pkt['TCP'].payload))):
                    
                    ########### any 3 below commands go in same error ############## 
                    ########### and i was try 'pss' instead of 'oaep' but same error 
                    
                    dec2 = k.decrypt(pkt['TCP'].payload, t='oaep')
                    #dec2 = k.decrypt(bytes(pkt['TCP'].payload), t='oaep')
                    #dec2 = k.decrypt(bytes(pkt['TCP'].payload).decode('UTF8', 'replace'), t='oaep')
                    
                    print(dec2)
                
    else:
        print('...passed')
```

If you have any solution then please share it and I will test and share the result with *no **negative** score*.

**NOTE**: I don't need ***Philosophy***, I have so many reference about that, I know so many developers say that this is impossible and make their Philosophy logics for it. please and please if you have the answer then share the code snippet references, if not leave it, because some groups solve this but they don't share their solutions. Tanx.

**example Groups That SOLVE this but not share their code:**
https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/10-1/pan-os-admin/decryption/decryption-concepts/tlsv13-ssl-decryption-support.html

Then **this is possible** but who knows the codes?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you want something that works like tshark then you'll have to have or write the code that's equivalent to what tshark uses. Or just use tshark's code.

Comment: Maybe my final solution will be customize tshark source code, But at this time I was write a Huge IDS/Firewall with Python+Scapy and I prefer to solve my problem with scapy libs.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do will be very difficult. Scapy/tshark deal with packet boundaries. You will need to deal with TCP reordering, out-of-order packets, tls messages and a whole set of other stuff. While decrypting of RSA sessions is possible if you have both the cert and key, it is not possible to do so for sessions that use ephemeral ciphers (elliptic curve). Even for RSA, like @president-james-k-polk mentioned you will pretty much have to implement what tshark is doing to create the decryption key.

Comment: I have the private key, but can not decrypt packets with no error... Do u have any clear solution for this?

Comment: @EyniKave As I said, this is not an easy thing to do. You have to essentially build a tls protocol stack. First, you accumulate all tls pkts in tls handshake msgs. During exchange, client sends cipher spec msg which includes premaster secret which is encrypted with the public key of svr. The svr will decrypt the secret using private key. The svr also sends change cipher spec which includes its side of the keying material. Once both sides have each other's keying material, they combine to create symmetric keys, used to encrypt user data. Leaving out lots of details, but this very involved.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not going to work. SSL/TLS certificates are only used for authentication in TLS 1.3 and in lower versions unless you configure the server to only support RSA key exchange your server is going to pick Diffie Hellman. If the client and server negotiate the use of Diffie Hellman (which again is mandatory for TLS 1.3,) then you can not decrypt data connections with the cert and the private key for the server even if you work through the issues you have in your code.

If you were to downgrade the version of TLS and configure the server to use RSA and browsers were willing to play ball by accepting the use of RSA then in theory what you want to do can be done but you're nowhere near the code you'd need. You seem to just be naively trying to decrypt all TLS/SSL packets with the private key for your server. This is not even close to what would work. You'd need to assemble the streams and identify the session key portion of the key exchange and decrypt that with the private key then use that to decrypt the rest of the data in the stream. As part of that you have to identify and track different streams (ie associate packets to them). This approach is a lot of work and frankly makes no sense.

Better approaches would be:

- Use a proxy like relayd or sslstrip that will act as the web server strip off the encryption and then forward unencrypted traffic between itself and your web server (you can just view this traffic)
- (still kinda crazy) modify the source to your web server to log all of it's traffic somewhere you can get it after the traffic has been decrypted.

Comment: This answer is not acceptable for me, but as i promised I will not give it negative score...
I was test some MITM packages but they not working exactly...
At this time I was solved my problem with NGINX custom logging format and watchdog to detect fast new TLS events for my TCP services Because nginx has MITM ability and if i want to use this solution then its enough... But in other hand I don't understand why this topic is very hard for most of developers because webservers like nginx or as u said MITM code can do that then as i said at first 'this must be so easy but world forget about it'

Comment: Like David Oldford explained, there is a DH key exchange that is part of  modern TLS exchanges. Therefore, even when you know the content of the secret key of the server certificate, you will not be able to get clear text with packet snooping. The only way to decrypt the content is to become an endpoint in the DH exchange, and this is called doing a MITM attack.

Comment: FALSE, for example TSHARK,ssldup,scapy,... are not endpoints but they try to do this but they has so many bugs and crash, in other hand they has focused on algorithms to decrypt with no private key and they forget about easy way that we have private key...
THEN it must be possible in packet sniffing , and it not must be endpoint...

Comment: or cisco in mercury project do that in packet sniffing in not endpoints https://github.com/cisco/mercury but I don't test it because not my favourite, I want to solve this in scapy or python and it must have a clear way but no one present a clear solution or code snippet :(

Comment: cisco's mercury sniffs metadata only.

Comment: Forward secrecy https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/definitions-of-secrecy

Comment: @EyniKave As I've explained already if you use TLS prior to 1.2 and force an RSA key exchange it is possible to do the type of decryption you want though a very large undertaking more of a github project than a stack overflow question. I've never used the tools you're talking about to do the thing you want to do though as I've explained under the conditions you've prescribed whether they try or not it isn't possible without breaking either the key exchange or symmetric cipher. Whether this answer is acceptable to you or not it is the correct answer.

Comment: key exchange or symmetric cipher , this is true, I know that, and I have all thing, I have packets that contains chiper text in server hello and main bundle,key,crt,... so where is the code snippt that i can use and work with no crash? you say this is possible and I know that ? the question is what is the code? then u not answer this question. sorry.

Comment: I say it's possible to decrypt the traffic if you don't use TLS 1.3 and you force RSA for key exchange. I didn't say breaking the key exchange or symmetric cipher were impossible because technically they aren't "impossible" they are just computationally infeasible. Having the RSA private key doesn't in any way assist in the effort for a Diffie Hellman exchange. As for how to do the decryption you want, if you drop TLS 1.3 and force the use of RSA as I've said it's a project not a question and to get started you need to move to processing connections instead of packets.

Comment: Tanx David, BUT what you said, I was already read in some articles and I think this is not complete and logical, For example webservers or web browsers can do that in the endpoints then I need a clean code snippet to that same as them in my endpoints, and can not find any solution or repo for this. I don't need MITM solutions because NGINX have proxy and custom logging ability that can prove MITM solutions... I search for a solution to dissect ssl packets in endpoint with scapy/python in sniffing process as legal and can not accept that this is impossible. may be was hard but not impossible.

Comment: As I've already said the crux of your problem is simply that you are wrong. I teach applied cryptography modules at a university. You're trying to break end to end encryption without access to the necessary keying material. The not impossible solution is just a straight attack on the ciphers. This is computationally infeasible and in layman's terms impossible. That's how crypto works. It's the whole point. It's one of the reasons TLS 1.3 enforces Diffie Hellman now. To be clear computationally infeasible in this case means the time to completion is likely after the sun burns out.

Comment: keying material is exist in packet series https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/tls/notebook2_tls_protected.ipynb and when we have the crypto main key and have material from streams then we must can decode the crypto . I just need the sample code and this is possible and happens in any https url that you visit in your browser, in 2 side client and server...  I don't need Philosophy, I just want a clear sample code.

Comment: You can decrypt, gain full visibility into, and prevent known and unknown threats in TLSv1.3 traffic. .... https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/10-1/pan-os-admin/decryption/decryption-concepts/tlsv13-ssl-decryption-support.html

Comment: "keying material is exist in packet series"

the symmetric session key is sent using Diffie Hellman key exchange which means the information you need to determine it is generated per connection and cannot be discerned from the RSA key. 

from your link "The firewall supports TLSv1.3 decryption for Forward Proxy, Inbound Inspection, decrypted Network Packet Broker traffic, and Decryption Port Mirroring."

So this is a firewall acting as a MITM. It uses the certificate to pretend to be the server so it's the one doing the key exchange and can determine the session keys.

Comment: look at the forward secrecy thing here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-on-top-of-tls-attacks/

and note that RSA was removed from TLS here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-tls-1-3/

This isn't philosophy this is how things work. MITM still works because the MITM is an endpoint participating in the crypto exchanges but spying from outside would require the server or the client to share per session information or for one of them to be predictable (which would be a massive security problem.) Your question is answered if you still don't believe me please read up on basic TLS.

Comment: Tanx David for your time and information, I will give you the bounty . As a final result I will go to use NGINX custom logging format + WatchDog to detect and interact fast with ssl requests.

Comment: @DavidOldford is correct, you cannot decrypt if ephemeral ciphers (diffie-helman) are used. U can decrypt the stream if RSA ciphers are used, but no one uses RSA on public networks these days. The exact algorithm on how to compute master secret from pre-master secret for RSA is given in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346. You can look at OpenSSL code to see what happens on both sides. What you are trying to do is play both sides by being an MITM/pcap. For that have to implement both sides of the protocol to be able to decrypt. It is possible but fairly involved.